# redux-saga spams with new requests after dispatching a single action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

So, basically, I have an action, that I dispatch on Button click. 
Here's my saga:

```
import * as TYPES from '../types';
import { call, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';

const url = `someApiUrl`;


const api = link => fetch(link, {
   method: 'GET'
}).then(res => res.json());

function* callingAPItoFetchNews (action) {
     try {
       const response = yield call(api, url);
       yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, payload: response});
     } catch (e) {
       yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEW_FAILED});
     }
}


export default function* watcherSaga () {
    yield takeLatest(TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, callingAPItoFetchNews)
}
```

and here's my root saga:

```
import { takeEvery, all, takeLatest, fork } from 'redux- saga/effects';
import * as TYPES from '../types';
import callingAPItoFetchNews  from '../sagas';

function* mySaga() {
    yield all ([
        fork(callingAPItoFetchNews)
    ])
}

export default mySaga;
```

After dispatching an action I see, that each fetch request is populated every second.
Actions itself looks just like that:

```
export const fetchNews = () => ({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS});
```

here is how I check the data that comes back basically:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        if (nextProps.dataLoaded !== undefined) {
            const articles = nextProps.dataLoaded.articles;
            const totalResults = nextProps.dataLoaded.totalResults;

            console.log('-----SEPARATION START-------');
            console.log(articles);
            console.log('-------SEPARATION END--------')
        }

    }
```

Here is my view where I connect app with redux and dispatch an action:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
Button,
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNews } from './actions'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import NavStack from './navigation';
import s from './styles';

class MainView extends React.PureComponent {

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.dataLoaded !== undefined) {
        const articles = nextProps.dataLoaded.articles;
        const totalResults = nextProps.dataLoaded.totalResults;

       console.log('-----SEPARATION START-------');
       console.log(articles);
       console.log('-------SEPARATION END--------')
    }

}

render() {
    return (
        //<NavStack/>
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
            <Button 
                title='Click me to fetch data'
                onPress={() => {
                    this.props.fetchNewsData();
                }}
            />
        </View>
        );
    }
}



mapStateToProps = state => ({
    dataLoaded: state.fetchNews.news
});

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchNewsData: () => dispatch(fetchNews())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainView);
```

Comment: how/where are you dispatching your action

Comment: @imjared Component added

Answer (score 1):

Your `takeLatest`:

```
takeLatest(TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, callingAPItoFetchNews)
```

is reacting on action that you `put`:

```
yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, payload: response});
```

You should use or *different name* or use `take` *instead*(and make solution with loop to catch event after handling first).

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as TYPES from '../types';
import { call, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';

const url = `someApiUrl`;


const api = link => fetch(link, {
   method: 'GET'
}).then(res => res.json());

function* callingAPItoFetchNews (action) {
     try {
       const response = yield call(api, url);
       yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, payload: response});
     } catch (e) {
       yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEW_FAILED});
     }
}


export default function* watcherSaga () {
    yield takeLatest(TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, callingAPItoFetchNews)
}
```

Because of the code above,

You can see that your code takes `TYPES.FETCH_NEWS` action and call api.

It is the problem when you also dispatch the same action `TYPES.FETCH_NEWS` when received a response from api by this line `yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS, payload: response});`.

To solve the problem with a standard way you should instead use new action type for api response. `yield put({type: TYPES.FETCH_NEWS_SUCCESS, payload: response});`